# Electronjs main page

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm building a Restaurant POS app in electron.

I'm trying to have a PinPad(password) as the first page of the app. Once the user is logged in will be able to take customer orders.

How can I define the PinPad as main page? And how do I create the route for user to see the main page to take customer order?

I have my PinPad source code and here is my [Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYG8w.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thank you for feedback I have edited the question. My question is; How can I define the PinPad as main page? And how do I create the route for user to see the main page to take customer order?

Answer (score 0):

To make the instance of your window change to a different source, all you need to do it call
Electron's [win.loadFile(filePath[, options])](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options)
method again.

Of course, this would only be done after you have validated the submission of a correct pin.

I have created a quick example below, noting the line of interest is at the end of the `main.js` file.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('pin-pad.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('pin', (event, pin) => {
    // Simple check of pin validity
    if (pin === '1234') {
        window.loadFile('sales.html'); // <-- Use this HTML file now...
    }
})
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electronAPI', {
        sendPin: (pin) => {
            ipcRenderer.send('pin', pin)
        }
    });
```

---

`pin-pad.html` (render process)

> Couldn't help but make it pretty

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test - Pin Pad</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>

        <style>
            #display {
                margin-bottom: 2em;
                padding: 0.25em;
                width: 9em;
                font-size: 1.25em;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #pin-pad {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: 4em 4em 4em 4em;
                grid-template-columns: 4em 4em 4em;
                grid-gap: 3px;
                user-select: none;
            }

            #pin-pad div {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                border: 1px solid #999;
                font-size: 1.25em;
            }

            #pin-pad div:hover {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="display" disabled>

        <div id="pin-pad">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>Enter</div>
            <div>0</div>
            <div>Clear</div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let display = document.getElementById('display');
        let validKeys = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','Enter','Clear'];
        let pin = '';

        document.getElementById('pin-pad').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (! validKeys.includes(event.target.innerText)) { return; }

            if (event.target.innerText === 'Enter') {
                window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
                return;
            }

            if (event.target.innerText === 'Clear') {
                pin = display.value = '';
                return;
            }

            pin = pin + event.target.innerText;
            display.value = '*'.repeat(pin.length);
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

---

`sales.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test - Sales</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sales</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```